# Como permitir um App a enviar notificação

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ios, mobile

Olá,

estou desenvolvendo um app e antes do login da pessoa, eu peço ao usuario a permissão para a localização do mesmo, isso ja esta ok, mas eu preciso colocar tambem em seguida, uma permissão para enviar notificações e eu não estou sabendo como fazer. Alguem poderia me dar uma ajuda?

dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: esse alerta é justamente para que o app envie o id do aparelho para o servidor e o servidor usa um serviço semelhante ao lambda da amazon para envio das notificações de qualquer forma vc tem q criar dentro do app um receiver para receber as notificações e mostrar na tela ou fazer uma determinada ação.

Comment: Poste o que você já tem para a localização. Fica mais fácil para te ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você pulou a etapa de configuração do Push Notification no projeto, para exibir o aviso de permissão, adicione o comando abaixo no .swift que você deseja tratar o aviso, este pode ser **appDelegate.swift** ou alguma controller:

```
func registrarUsuarioParaPushNotifications() {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current() // 1
    .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { // 2
      granted, error in
      print("Permission granted: \(granted)") // 3
  }
}
```

Explicação do comando acima:

- **UNUserNotificationCenter** manipula todas as notificações relacionadas as atividades do App - [Documentação oficial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter);
- Você invoca **requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:)** para solicitar autorização para exibir notificações. As opções passadas indicam o tipo de notificação que você quer que seu app use. No exemplo, nós estamos solicitando alerta, som e badge - [Documentação oficial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorization)
- O **completion handler** recebe uma boleana na qual indica se a autoriação foi bem sucedida. No caso, estamos apenas printando o resultado;

Se precisar de mais detalhes, recomendo ler este [guia](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started)